# How Get ids from array response vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

hello let's say i have a response data using axios vue js from laravel :

my example :

```
getApps(page = 1){


 
     axios.get('/api/getappforms')
     .then(response =>
     { 

   apps = response.data
  
 }
     ).catch(err => console.log(err));



}
```

and my laravel method :

```
$DataApps = Appclications::select('application.*','wilayas.name as wilaya','dairas.name as daira_field','communes.name as commune_field')
->leftJoin('dairas','dairas.id','=','application.id_daira')
->leftJoin('wilayas','wilayas.id','=','application.id_wilaya')

->leftJoin('communes','communes.id','=','application.id_commune')
->paginate(15);


    return   response()->json($DataApps);
```

every thing works fine just i want to fetch or get just ids in vue js from apps var and stored in another array

please help

Comment: can you the updated response Object that you are currently getting in the question?

Comment: every thing works with me just i want to  get ids from  apps :{}  / i am confused if need to use filter or there is another solution

Comment: Dude only if you share the response json...only then I ll be able to help

Comment: without even sharing the response how can you expect us to post a solution...

Comment: i share the respone data in the answer thanks :)

Comment: Check my updated answer...also pls remove your answer and update the json in the question

Answer (score 0):

My response data :

```
{"current_page":1,
"data":[{"id_app":1,"name":"soheib","last_name":"madi","phone":"23923923",
"position":"reghaia","situation":"dsdd",
"date_born":"2021-01-04","photo_profile":null,
"nb_children":2,"id_wilaya":5,"id_daira":542,"id_commune":149,
"email":"me@ma.com","job_field":"T\u00e9l\u00e9surveillance",
"militaire":null,"anem":"yes","field_motivation":"je ve ce travail","created_at":"2021-01-24T23:46:05.000000Z",
"updated_at":"2021-01-24T23:46:05.000000Z","wilaya":"Batna","daira_field":"Barika",
"commune_field":"M Doukal"},
{"id_app":2,"name":"soheib",
"last_name":"madi","phone":"23923923",
"position":"reghaia","situation":"dsdd","date_born":"2021-01-04","photo_profile":null,"nb_children":2,"id_wilaya":5,
"id_daira":542,"id_commune":149,"email":"me@ma.com",
"job_field":"T\u00e9l\u00e9surveillance",
"militaire":null,"anem":"yes","field_motivation":"je ve ce travail","created_at":"2021-01-24T23:47:28.000000Z",
"updated_at":"2021-01-24T23:47:28.000000Z","wilaya":"Batna",
"daira_field":"Barika","commune_field":"M Doukal"},{"id_app":3,"name":"soheib","last_name":"madi",
"phone":"23923923","position":"reghaia",
"situation":"dsdd","date_born":"2021-01-04","photo_profile":null,"nb_children":2,"id_wilaya":5,
"id_daira":542,"id_commune":149,"email":"me@ma.com",
"job_field":"T\u00e9l\u00e9surveillance",
"militaire":null,"anem":"yes",
"field_motivation":"je ve ce travail","created_at":"2021-01-24T23:49:58.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-01-24T23:49:58.000000Z","wilaya":"Batna","daira_field":"Barika","commune_field":"M Doukal"}],
"first_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost:3000\/api\/getappforms?page=1","from":1,
"last_page":1,
"last_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost:3000\/api\/getappforms?page=1","links":[{"url":null,"label":"&laquo; Previous","active":false},{"url":"http:\/\/localhost:3000\/api\/getappforms?page=1",
"label":1,"active":true},
{"url":null,"label":"Next &raquo;","active":false}],"next_page_url":null,
"path":"http:\/\/localhost:3000\/api\/getappforms",
"per_page":15,"prev_page_url":null,"to":6,"total":6}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract just the id's you can do like this

```
getApps(page = 1){
  axios.get('/api/getappforms')
   .then(response =>
   { 
   let apps = response.data
   console.log(apps); // to check if its an array
   let ids = apps.map(item => return item.id);
   console.log(ids); // this will print your ids array  
   }
).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: `
    this.apps = response.data;
   let ids = this.apps.map(item =>  { return data.id } );
   console.log(ids); // this will print your ids array  `  probelm is map not a function

Comment: the comment typed is different from my answer...moreover before the map line try printing the apps and confirm if thats really an array

Answer (score 0):

thanks , i found the solution :

```
getApps(page = 1){


 
     axios.get('/api/getappforms')
     .then(response =>
     { 

    this.apps = response.data;
   let ids = this.apps.data.map((item) => { return item.id_app  }   );
   console.log(ids); // this will print your ids array  
 }
     ).catch(err => console.log(err));



}
```